Antix linux: большие проблемы со звуком после апгрейда пакетов
Введение
Установил себе на флешку Antix linux версии 23. Использую эту флешку как легковесную переносную рабочую среду (очень удобно). Чаще всего загружаюсь с неё на двух компьютерах: на рабочем ПК и на своём домашнем. Пока не обновил пакеты, проблем со звуком не было: воспроизводился на обоих компах.
Часть 1
И так, после обновления пакетов с помощью apt upgrade неожиданно пропал звук на домашнем ПК. Зашёл в 'Menu -> Control Center -> Hardware' и принудительно выбрал аудио-карту - вроде всё заработало, звук появился. Однако потом, когда я загрузил систему на рабочем ПК, звука опять не было! Причём, как выяснилось, не было его под обычным пользователем, а при запуске того же аудиоплеера под рутом, звук прекрасно работал. Потратив большую часть дня на поиск проблемы, я обнаружил, что если удалить/переместить файл /home/<my_user_name>/.asoundrc, звук сразу начинал нормально воспроизводиться, а когда возвращал этот файл обратно - снова пропадал. Что я и сделал, переместил этот файл в другое место. Однако радость моя была ровно до тех пор, пока я не пришёл домой...
Часть 2
Когда я загрузился со своего домашнего ПК, то обнаружил, что... sic! Звука снова нет!)))) Вернул обратно файл .asoundrc - не помогло. Опять зашёл в 'Menu -> Control Center -> Hardware', чтобы вручную выбрать мою аудиокарту и... мне высветился список аудиоустройств с рабочего ПК! Аудиокарты с моего ПК перестали отображаться вовсе!
И так, результат команды alsactl init:
Found hardware: "HDA-Intel" "ATI R6xx HDMI" "HDA:1002aa01,00aa0100,00100700" "0x1002" "0xab38"
Hardware is initialized using a generic method
Found hardware: "HDA-Intel" "Realtek ALC1220" "HDA:10ec1220,1458a0c3,00100101" "0x1458" "0xa0c3"
Hardware is initialized using a generic method

"HDA-Intel" - это устройства с рабочего ПК, ожидаемо. Карточек с текущего домашнего ПК не отображает.
Команда cat /proc/asound/cards:
 0 [HDMI           ]: HDA-Intel - HDA ATI HDMI
                      HDA ATI HDMI at 0xfcca0000 irq 116
 1 [Generic        ]: HDA-Intel - HD-Audio Generic
                      HD-Audio Generic at 0xfce00000 irq 118

Результат также ожидаемый - запущены аудиодрайвера для рабочего ПК.
Команда aplay -l выдаёт следующее:
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: HDMI [HDA ATI HDMI], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: HDMI [HDA ATI HDMI], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: HDMI [HDA ATI HDMI], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: HDMI [HDA ATI HDMI], device 9: HDMI 3 [PHL 240P4QPY]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: HDMI [HDA ATI HDMI], device 10: HDMI 4 [HDMI 4]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: HDMI [HDA ATI HDMI], device 11: HDMI 5 [HDMI 5]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: Generic [HD-Audio Generic], device 0: ALC1220 Analog [ALC1220 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: Generic [HD-Audio Generic], device 1: ALC1220 Digital [ALC1220 Digital]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

Тут я, если честно, не понял, что за девайсы отображаются.
А вот результат команды lspci | grep Audio:
0c:00.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Navi 10 HDMI Audio
0e:00.3 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) HD Audio Controller

А она показывает уже реальные аудиоустройства на моём домашнем ПК! Значит получается, что с драйверами всё в порядке? Просто они, по какой-то причине не загружаются (а вместо них грузятся драйвера для другого компа)?
И для полноты картины, результат команды inxi -F (без секций 'Network' и 'Drives'):
System:
  Host: LShadow77PC Kernel: 6.1.60-antix.1-amd64-smp arch: x86_64 bits: 64
    Desktop: IceWM v: 3.4.5 Distro: antiX-23.1_x64-full Arditi del Popolo 21
    February 2024
Machine:
  Type: Desktop System: Gigabyte product: X470 AORUS ULTRA GAMING v: N/A
    serial: N/A
  Mobo: Gigabyte model: X470 AORUS ULTRA GAMING-CF serial: N/A UEFI: American
    Megatrends LLC. v: F63b date: 05/11/2022
CPU:
  Info: 6-core model: AMD Ryzen 5 2600X bits: 64 type: MT MCP cache: L2: 3 MiB
  Speed (MHz): avg: 2433 min/max: 2200/3600 cores: 1: 2200 2: 2200 3: 2200
    4: 2200 5: 2200 6: 3600 7: 2200 8: 2200 9: 2200 10: 2200 11: 2200 12: 3600
Graphics:
  Device-1: AMD Navi 10 [Radeon RX 5600 OEM/5600 XT / 5700/5700 XT]
    driver: amdgpu v: kernel
  Display: x11 server: X.Org v: 1.21.1.7 driver: X: loaded: amdgpu
    unloaded: fbdev,modesetting,radeon,vesa dri: radeonsi gpu: amdgpu
    resolution: 1920x1200~60Hz
  API: EGL v: 1.5 drivers: radeonsi,swrast
    platforms: gbm,x11,surfaceless,device
  API: OpenGL v: 4.6 vendor: amd mesa v: 22.3.6 renderer: AMD Radeon RX
    5700 XT (navi10 LLVM 15.0.6 DRM 3.49 6.1.60-antix.1-amd64-smp)
Audio:
  Device-1: AMD Navi 10 HDMI Audio driver: snd_hda_intel
  Device-2: AMD Family 17h HD Audio driver: snd_hda_intel
  API: ALSA v: k6.1.60-antix.1-amd64-smp status: kernel-api
Partition:
  ID-1: / size: 17.37 GiB used: 8.49 GiB (48.9%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/sdc2
  ID-2: /home size: 11.11 GiB used: 4.31 GiB (38.8%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/sdc3
Swap:
  ID-1: swap-1 type: file size: 2 GiB used: 0 KiB (0.0%) file: /swap/swap
Sensors:
  System Temperatures: cpu: 44.1 C mobo: N/A gpu: amdgpu temp: 47.0 C
  Fan Speeds (rpm): N/A gpu: amdgpu fan: 0
Info:
  Processes: 285 Uptime: 24m Memory: total: 16 GiB available: 15.54 GiB
  used: 1.85 GiB (11.9%) Shell: Bash inxi: 3.3.31

Как видно, в секции 'Audio' также отображаются реальные на этом компе устройства (AMD, а не Intel).
Вопрос
Как это исправить? Чую, что где-то что-то напортачено с конфигами. Вопрос: где и что? Проблема не должна быть прям фундаментальной, ведь до апгрейда звук воспроизводился как часы на любом ПК: система корректно определяла и инициализировала аудиоустройство как на рабочем ПК, так на домашнем ПК тоже. Апгрейд пакетов это сломал. Я устал гуглить, очень надеюсь на вашу помощь!
P.S.
Предвидя вопрос "Почему AntiX", ответ: слабое железо на рабочем ПК, Убунту его не потянет.
PP.S.
Всё таки меня смущают строки:
Device-1: AMD Navi 10 HDMI Audio driver: snd_hda_intel
Device-2: AMD Family 17h HD Audio driver: snd_hda_intel

Т.е., карта от AMD, а драйвера от Intel? Что-то здесь не чисто...
